# How do I get rid of these inexplicable design-time errors in an empty App.xaml?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, app.xaml

I have an issue with `App.xaml` in a Silverlight 5 application project. Basically, I can remove everything (resources inside `<Application.Resources>`, such as styles and converters) from it, until I am left with only this:

```
<Application x:Class="SomeProject.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

But Visual Studio 2013's *Error List* window will still list below three (ignorable) design-time errors:

> - The property "Resources" can only be set once. (App.xaml, Line 1, Column 1)
> - The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary". (App.xaml, Line 1, Column 1)
> - The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "ResourceDictionary". (App.xaml, Line 1, Column 1)

These are purely design-time errors; I can successfully compile and run the project. However, the errors don't make any sense, and they are annoying.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

Some things I've tried already:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the whole solution.
- Manually wiping the `App.g.i.*` files in the `obj` artifact directory.
- Manually deleting the `obj` and `bin` directories.
- I made sure that `App.xaml` is in the main Silverlight application project (not in some other class library); and there is no other project item of type "ApplicationDefinition".

Comment: So you manually del'd your /bin & /obj folders? (which is all cleaning is doing for ya anyway) and you rebuilt, and it looks like the other step would be fine and you're still getting it? This may sound really dumb, but speaking from experience in SL, have you tried just restarting your machine? (I know, sounds dumb, but you'd be surprised...)

Comment: Yes, I even deleted the `bin` and `obj` directories... several times in fact. I haven't tried a restart yet, but I'll give it a try tomorrow and report back here.

Comment: @ChrisW.: I don't quite believe it, but restarting the development machine indeed made these errors disappear! If you re-post your above comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah the joys of Silverlight development... While I don't have a completely competent technical answer to your question, I've found that restarting your machine can do magical things (I know, no true developer ever wants to hear the word "magical" in a fix) but one could assume there's a caching issue somewhere...

However the point is restarting can often clear up erroneous errors related to build time resources that you would normally expect a quick clean to fix.

Anyhow, glad you got a remedy. Cheers!